# Add Credentials for Azure Nuget Feed in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am moving my existing project to a new machine. I am using a custom Azure Nuget feed with a url in the form:

https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/project/_packaging/project.Libs/nuget/v3/index.json

When I try to build, I get the error:

> NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source
> https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/project/_packaging/project.Libs/nuget/v3/index.json
> Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

I also cannot browse the packages in the feed.

I am logged in in my browser and can see the content of the json file of the feed but of course not in a private session.

On my old machine I don't remember how the feed was added and I also haven't saved my username/password anywhere (e.g. in NuGet.config, which seems to be a suggested solution).

Does anyone know how to provide the credential to VS so that it can access the feed?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix this by:

- Logging out of Visual Studio (top right)
- Creating a new project and adding a new Nuget feed from the URL of my Azure artifacts
- Nuget asked me to login again and the account I had been using was listed there. I did **not** select it but said "use another account"
- I logged in again with the same account, providing username, password and two factor authentication

Now everything works fine.

Comment: So weird.. this worked for me as well - HOWEVER, I have to do this every time I open a project/solution 

Comment: Me too, I've this same problem with the Visual Studio 2022 Professional Edition