# Visual Studio 2022 cannot read Private Nuget Feed

Tags: azure, nuget, visual-studio-2022, azure-artifacts

I created an Azure Artifact Nuget feed and I published a library there.
Now I want to build a project that references that project.
I added the new Package Source in Visual Studio 2022, but when I select my source, the credentials pop up appears, I select my account and this happens

[image: Error in Visual Studio]

The error is very generic, even though it says 401. However, the user is the same one I'm using to connect to Azure, so I know it is correct.

I already followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72395187/add-credentials-for-azure-nuget-feed-in-visual-studio) but that solution didn't work.

Can I get more details on the error or try a different authentication method to see if it is really an authentication issue?

Thanks

Comment: Try configure in the Nuget.config file(Global environment configuration, which will affect vs), that should make it continue working. :)

Comment: You can check this document [Azure DevOps Artifacts authentication issues](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Azure-DevOps-Artifacts-authentication-issues). It   introduces some common solutions to the 401 (Unauthorized) error.  You can use a network tracing tool, such as Fiddler, to get more details on the error.

Answer (score 2):

Refer this [**MS document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/consume?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows) to connect ***Azure Artifact*** **`nuget`** feed to Visual Studio and reference it in your Project.

I select my feed from ***Artifacts section of my project*** and ***select Connect to Feed:-***

[image]

***Now Open Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Nuget Package Manager > Package sources > Add new Package source > In the Name add the name of your Azure Artifacts feed > And Source URL copied from the previous step:-***

[image]

***Now select Nuget Package manager > Manage Nuget package for solution >  Select Your Feed  > Login to your Azure Devops account which has access to Artifact > and install your private feed package in your project:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

**My `csproj` file:-**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="0004-New-AzureRmVmAvailabilitySetPsg" Version="1.1.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Data.Tables" Version="12.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```